# c++ stringstream into variables of different types

Tags: c++, c, dynamic, casting, type-conversion

I'm getting a string containing raw binary data which needs to be converted to integers. The Problem is these values are not always in the same order and do not always appear. So the format of the binary data gets described in a config file and the type of the values read from the binary data is *not* known at compile time.

I'm thinking of a solution similar to this:

```
enum BinaryType {
  TYPE_UINT16,
  TYPE_UNIT32,
  TYPE_INT32
};

long convert(BinaryType t, std::stringstream ss) {
  long return_value;
  switch(t) {
    case TYPE_UINT16:
      unsigned short us_value;
      ss.read(&us_value, sizeof(unsigned short));
      return_value = short;
    break;
    case TYPE_UINT32:
      unsigned int ui_value;
      ss.read(&ui_value, sizeof(unsigned int));
      return_value = ui_value;
    break;
    case TYPE_INT32:
      signed int si_value;
      ss.read(&si_value, sizeof(signed int));
      return_value = si_value;
    break;
  }
  return return_value;
}
```

The goal is to output these values in decimal.

My Questions are:

- This code is very repetitive. Is there a simpler solution? (Templates?)
- should I make use of the standard types like `signed int` if the value needs to be 32 bit? What to use instead? Endianness?

Comment: As you can not rely on `long` being larger then 32 bit you might lose information in case of `t`being `TYPE_UINT32`.

Comment: Templates will help a little, but they're not necessarily a panacea. If the type you are reading is not known at compile time, you'll still need the `switch` block, for example.

Comment: Use any integer type guaranteed to be larger then 32 bit. @Mogria

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution: define a base class for converters:

```
class Converter {
public:
virtual int_64 convert(std::stringstream& ss) = 0;
}
```

Next define a concrete converter for each binary type. Have a map/array mapping from binary types identifiers to your converters, e.g.:

```
Converter* converters[MAX_BINARY_TYPES];
converters[TYPE_UINT16] = new ConverterUINT16;
...
```

Now, you can use it like this (variables defined like in your function convert):

```
cout << converters[t]->convert(ss)
```

For portability, instead of basic types like int, long, etc, you should use int32_t, int64_t which are guaranteed to be the same on all systems.

Of course, if your code is meant to deal with different endianness, you need to deal with it explicitly. For the above example code you can have two different converters' sets, one for little endian data decoding, another for big endian. Another thing you can do is to write a wrapper class for std::stringstream, let's call it StringStream, which defines functions for reading int32, uint32, etc., and swaps the bytes if the endianness is different than the architecture of the system your code is running on. You can make the class a template and instantiate it with one of the two:

```
class SameByteOrder {
public:
    template<typename T> static void swap(T &) {}
};

class OtherByteOrder {
public:
    template<typename T> static void swap(T &o)
    {
        char *p = reinterpret_cast<char *>(&o);
        size_t size = sizeof(T);
        for (size_t i=0; i < size / 2; ++i)
            std::swap(p[i], p[size - i - 1]);
    }
};
```

then use the swap function inside your StringStream's functions to swap (or not) the bytes.

Comment: Regarding endianess issues the use of the `ntoh` family of functions is an option.

Comment: @alk yeah, that depends on the protocol or format of the binary data. If the format says data is always in the so called 'network byte order' then you can use `ntoh` etc. But, I have seen formats where binary data is always saved in host byte order, for performance reasons. When you read the data you first check a byte order indicator, and swap the bytes if necessary.